# How to return to home screen from Activity

Tags: android, onclicklistener, homescreen, android-imagebutton

I know Android will return to the home screen when I press the Home key, however,
I want my imageButton to behave as the Home key, which can inform the home screen to the foreground.

How should I implement my onClickListener to accomplish this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    startActivity(intent);
```