# Don't make the application start once again after pressing "Close"

Tags: android, eclipse, android-activity

I'm using the following code to switch between activities:

```
Intent b = new Intent(nowActivity.this, About.class);
startActivity(b);
return true;
```

This code works perfectly but it seems to make it start a new activity on top of the existing activity.

**Example**: I start the application on my Android phone and pressing the menu button to make the optionsmenu up on the screen. I then hit "About" to go to the about page for the application. If I then pressing the "Close" option in the menu, the first page (home screen of the application) will be visible on the screen and everything is back to square 1, just like I was opening the application once again.

I don't want it to act like this and I asking you now, how can I fix this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is not clear what you want after clicking on close button

Comment: The application will close after I'm pressing the "Close" button. It's make sense you know

Comment: You want to make the activity run only single time ?

Comment: See my comment for Nishant's answer.

Comment: try to be specific what you want to implement, so that get what exactly you are trying to do

Comment: @Agarwal: You mean that my question wasn't clear enough? :P

Comment: @ErikEdgren: Means you want a single activity to Made run Once only, and afterwords when i click that activity it does not run Second time ?

Comment: Yes exactly, there is a bit confusion what you are tring to do.

Comment: from first activity you are about activity from about activity you are pressing menu->close. so it must close the app or only about activity or anything else it should do....

Comment: @Agarwal: Um. I stated my problem quite clear in my question. When I start the application and go to "About" and after that pressing "Close" the application will shutdown but re-open again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working! Here's the solution:

**nowActivity.java**

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.menuItem1:
        Toast.makeText(this, "Du är redan på startsidan", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return false;

    case R.id.menuItem2:
        Intent b = new Intent(nowActivity.this, About.class);
        b.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(b);
        return true;

    case R.id.menuItem3:
        android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
        return true;

    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**About.java**

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.menuItem1:
        Intent a = new Intent(About.this, nowActivity.class);
        a.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(a);
        return true;

    case R.id.menuItem2:
        Toast.makeText(this, "Du är redan på \"Om\"-sidan", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return false;

    case R.id.menuItem3:
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
        startActivity(intent);
        System.exit(0);
        return true;

    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

edit your code: call finish() to destroy the first activity

```
Intent b = new Intent(nowActivity.this, About.class);
startActivity(b);
finish();
return true;
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't want to close the activity when switching to a new activity. When I'm hitting the back button on my phone, the application will go back one step (from "About" to "Home" for example). If I press the same button once again, the application will close unless I choose "Close" first.

Comment: Thank you :) Those answers was kinda neat but see my comment for hopia's answer.

Answer (score 0):

How about going back to the Home screen when the user clicks on your "Close" button?

The following code is taken from: 
[How to return to home screen from Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5900276/how-to-return-to-home-screen-from-activity)

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Thanks! That solved my issue a little. When I'm pressing the back button on my phone the application closes, even if the application should go back to "Home".